# Gravel bike frame material: carbon, aluminum, titaniul or steel?

Tags: frames, steel, aluminum, gravel, titanium

For a long ride on a gravel bike, what is the best frame material?

Comment: It is more a question of geometry than of frame material.

Comment: If I were really on gravel I'd want steel or titanium.

Comment: This question may be inherently too opinion based to answer objectively. It's likely that all materials can be made comfortable - even aluminum, these days.

Comment: If it’s about comfort: You can make a comfortable bike out of basically any (solid) material. When it comes to mass carbon is usually superior.

Comment: "Steel is real" but really this is to vague and opinion based to give a good answer too/

Comment: The best frame material is the one you can obtain nowdays, that is comfortable for you that you can afford.  Good luck.

Comment: Best for what - best for the environment is certainly not carbon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR
When selecting a frame / bike the most important factor is that you have decided for yourself what you like in ride feel for your application. Test ride several bikes and develop your knowledge of what feels good to you / fits your riding style and then buy the bike that works best for you. You may want to rent different bikes so you can test them in the environment of your choice.
Most good bike shops will let you test ride bikes. Even though it's only in the parking lot it's better than nothing.

**Craftsmanship Matters**
Assuming a reasonable level of material quality, frame design and construction can have a greater effect on ride quality than whether it's made of aluminum, titanium, steel, or carbon fiber. Selecting "the right" gravel frame is not as simple as selecting "the right" material.

By adding material here, removing material there, changing the shape of the tubing, changing the frame angles - and many other techniques a good frame designer will adjust the characteristics of the material to achieve a design goal.
Design goals include (but are not limited to) comfort, or stiffness, or stability, nimbleness, or some combination. Your mission is to find a frame designed to match your needs.

Just one example of this is an old Cannondale SR400 vs. an old Raleigh Technium. Both frames are made of aluminum and both are road bikes The two bikes have very different ride characteristics because they are constructed in very different ways.